# Randomness generated by deterministic processes

Tags: terminology, randomness

The tag excerpt of [randomness](/questions/tagged/randomness) says:

> Randomness <...> can also be generated by deterministic processes.

Is that not intrinsically contradictory? Or does it consider randomness epistemically where an ontologically deterministic process appears random when insufficient conditioning information is available (an example of pseudo random number generator comes to mind -- thanks to Tim)? If not, could you offer a clarifying example?

<sub>P.S. The other part of the excerpt is *Randomness is often modeled with probability distributions, but can also be generated by deterministic processes.* In my opinion, this sounds like an apples-to-oranges comparison, making the use of *but* questionable.</sub>

Comment: Either someone meant PRNGs, or this is a deeply philosophical comment.

Comment: Had to Google *PRNG*. It turns out to be *pseudo random number generator*.

Comment: It's a pretty bad tag wiki -- an anonymous user contributed it long ago and (apparently) it was never seriously reviewed.  Discussing bad tag wikis is the province of our Meta site: does it really belong here?

Comment: @whuber, to the extent that the question is about statistical concepts and their definitions, I think it is more at home here than on Meta. I have phrased the question so as to discuss a statistical claim, not to discuss the properties of the excerpt for its own sake. Had I focused on editing the excerpt instead, I would have posted it on Meta. Perhaps the P.S. got in the way... I hope that makes sense.

Answer (score 1):

one example that comes to mind that I saw being used as an example in a similar context, is calculating digits of pi or sqrt(2) or any other irrational number. The individual digits are uniformly distributed as far as we know with no relationship between the previous digits and the next digits. You don't know what the next digit will be until you observe it, e.i., compute it, so you can say that it will be random, but of course completely deterministic.

Yes, this is similar to how the pseudo-random numbers are computed. So is it random or pseudo-random? Is the billionth billionth billionth digit of pi that we won't be able to compute until hundred years from now less random than a decay time of some specific atom? You decide

**edit:**
digits of pi or sqrt of 2 are going to pass pretty much any randomness criteria used to test pseudo-random generators, which is not the case for other pseudorandom generators. At least that's what mathematicians believe, I a not sure, I am not a number theorist

Comment: Thank you. I wonder how to characterize the process that generates the digits of $\pi$ or $\sqrt{2}$. Can we say it is a deterministic process? (I do not have an immediate answer.)

Comment: Determining whether $\pi,$ $\sqrt{2},$ or other (easily expressed) irrational numbers is a *normal number* in this sense is [an unresolved problem](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/NormalNumber.html).  The computation of their digits bears little similarity to the generation of pseudo-random numbers

Comment: it is definitely deterministic since everybody will get the same answer, or you will get the same answer if you calculate it again. It is already determined what the digits are if you wish.

Comment: @whuber thanks that's exactly what I had in mind. The similarity is that they are results of computing some mathematical function. If this is a big or small similarity is I guess a matter of opinion.